# When I clone a file input, the cloned input does not keep the uploaded file. The original input does

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, input, input-type-file

When I clone an input type file, It so happens that the file uploaded to the cloned input gets attached to the original input. Its as if the cloned input is representing and taking attachments for the original.

Im cloning it the following way:
clonedInput = $('input[type=file]').clone(true)
is it posible to clone a file input and use it independently?
or is there another way to solve this.

On the dom, the user has the option to upload more than one file by clicking on a button that duplicates the first input, but the duplicate does not work because it attached the file to the original input.

Comment: You can not set the value of an input. So the clone will not have the value. Also with modern browsers, the user should be able to select multiple files with one input. Do you really need that?

Comment: It sounds like you possibly need to manually give the cloned input a unique ID otherwise the clone could be using the same ID as the original and thus the attachment is associated with the original input too.

Comment: I did change the id and name attribute, but it is still not working. And actually I do have the multiple attribute , but the user should be able to clone the form that contains the file input for a second submission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the problem was to convert the html into a string with .prop("outerHTML"), then convert it back to a html element with $.parseHTML() so the dom would treat it as a brand new or fresh element.

Comment: That's a bit of a hackish way to do it. Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use `multiple` attribute to upload multiple files at single `input type="file"` element

```
<input type="file" multiple />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the cloned item a unique ID with something like this:

```
clonedInput = $('input[type=file]').clone(true).attr("id",function(i,oldVal) {
            return oldVal.replace(/\d+/,function(m){
                return (+m + 1);
            });
```